# Is there a way to make a profile page that is responsive (for both mobile and desktop

Tags: php, html

So I have installed wordpress on my server, and it looks wonderful there. I would love to have a profile/front page for my website that is displayed nicely on phones/tablets and desktop. I have been looking around for this for a loong time but I have been unable to find anything.
It would be great if it looks like: http://about.me/hansstam (my current profile page, but not self-hosted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to read about media queries. They allow your page to adapt to screen sized allowing your content to be enhanced for mobile and desktop browsing. take a look here:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: perfect, just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at WP-Touch:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/
or alternatively use Themes/Frameworks that have this functionality built in, like the Roots theme. When using your very own theme, then have a look at CSS3 media queries http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/ or Javascript libraries like adapt.js http://adapt.960.gs/